# Grouping in GWT visualization API (or: Thousands delimiter in google charts using Java)

Tags: gwt, google-visualization, number-formatting

I want to create a DataTable using the class com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable.

In the underlying JavaScript API, google.visualization.NumberFormat provides this option (from https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformatter)

> groupingSymbol    A character to be used to group digits to the left of the decimal into sets of three. Default is a comma (,).

The Java class doesn't seem to have that property. How can I set the grouping symbol, or the number format as format string, for a column in my Java code? I tried

```
private static native void formatDataTable(DataTable dataTable, int numericColumn)
/*-{
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
        {groupingSymbol: '.'});
    formatter.format(dataTable, numericColumn);
}-*/;
```

but I only got

> ...[ERROR] - Uncaught exception escaped...google is not defined

in the development mode console in eclipse.

EDIT: code sample corrected

Comment: Did you try something like ˋ$wnd.google.load?ˋ. Direct access to global variables is kind of a weird thing in GWT.

Comment: That was it. If you make it an answer I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using JSNI you can't access global variables the way you access with regular Javascript. From the [documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html):

> When accessing the browser’s window and document objects from JSNI,
>   you must reference them as $wnd and $doc, respectively. Your compiled
>   script runs in a nested frame, and $wnd and $doc are automatically
>   initialized to correctly refer to the host page’s window and document.

So, for your code to work, you need to use:

```
var formatter = new $wnd.google.visualization.NumberFormat({groupingSymbol: '.'});
```